# I want to set actionbar color and title in a fragment class which is in tablayout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This is my tabhost Activity and i want to set each fragment title at actionbar.My tabs are at bottom in xml and i want each tab title at top in actionbar.Can we write code in this tabhostActivity?Or can write any code in each fragment.Can anyone suggest any option for this?

```
public class TabHostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.hm_icon,
        R.drawable.a_icon,
        R.drawable.user_icon_white,
        R.drawable.gear,
        R.drawable.mail_icon_white
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

   /* setSupportActionBar(toolbar);*/
    /*getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);*/

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();


    permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS);


    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);

    }
}
private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(tabIcons[4]);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new HomeMain(), "");
    adapter.addFrag(new ChooseDefault(), "");
    adapter.addFrag(new MyAccountActivity(), "");
    adapter.addFrag(new UtitlityFragment(), "");
    adapter.addFrag(new SMSFragment(), "");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone have any suggestion

Comment: Down votes for a person who just joined stack overflow? Obviously the person is new here and needs some time to ask a good question. Down vote for him at so early stage might have de-motivated him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this to get your desired outcome.

```
YourTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        int pos = tab.getPosition();
        String title = YourFragmentTitle.get(pos);
        YourActionBarObject.setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: YourFragmentTitle what is this?

Comment: In your case it is "mFragmentTitleList"

Comment: Try again with this and tell me if the same error persists

Comment: mFragmentTitleList.add("Home");
        mFragmentTitleList.add("Add");
        mFragmentTitleList.add("My Account");
        mFragmentTitleList.add("Utility");
        mFragmentTitleList.add("Message");     added list like this.Sill same error

Comment: what you put in yourActionBarObject?

Comment: Perfect ...it wrkz...:).... i changed mActionBar=getActionBar to getSupportActionBar... Thank u

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener.html)

```
mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            final int position = tab.getPosition();
            final String title = mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
            mActionBar.setTitle(titleRes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is this mFragmentTitleList?

Comment: got error  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (mActionBar != null) {
            mActionBar.setTitle(title);
        }